# Is there a difference between "plagiarizer" and "plagiarist"?

Tags: differences, word-usage

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) lists [plagiarist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plagiarist) as the noun form of plagiarism and lists [plagiarizer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plagiarizer) as the noun form of plagiarize. I do not see the distinction of the separate entries and expected both words to be listed as noun forms.

Comment: What leads you to suspect they might mean something different?

Comment: What leads you to suspect they might mean something... _different_?

Comment: A plagiarizer is merely a hack. A plagiarist is an _artist_.

Comment: A plagiarizer gets caught. A plagiarist gets published.

Comment: In AmE, we use, for example, _piano player_ to describe someone who earns a living playing the piano, maybe with a band or in the lobby of a hotel or other places where background music is desired. The label _pianist_, however, is **usually** reserved for people who play classical music on the concert circuit, eg, Arthur Rubinstein & Van Cliburn. The term is also used for famous jazz and popular piano players and composers like Duke Ellington, Billy Joel, & Stevie Wonder. A _forger_ is always a forger & never a _forgist_, no matter how skilled. A _copyist_, not a _copier_, makes copies.

Comment: @BillFranke My copier makes copies.

Comment: @MετάEd: But it's a machine, not a person. Different entities, different usage rules. Context is **almost** all. :-)

Comment: There indeed was a *copyist* appointed to run the *copier*, seriously. (Perhaps on the lines of *typist*-*typewriter*). http://www.google.com/search?as_qdr=all&q=copyist&tbs=dfn:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many<sup>1</sup> *-ist/-izer* pairs in which one could imagine some difference in meaning between them, such as in (perhaps) at least some of these pairs:

- agonist, agonizer
- Americanist, Americanizer
- antagonist, antagonizer
- apologist, apologizer
- baptist, baptizer
- botanist, botanizer
- dramatist, dramatizer
- economist, economizer
- generalist, generalizer
- hypnotist, hypnotizer
- Ionist, ionizer
- journalist, journalizer
- localist, localizer
- maximist, maximizer
- minimist, minimizer
- modernist, modernizer
- monopolist, monopolizer
- moralist, moralizer
- naturalist, naturalizer
- novelist, novelizer
- optimist, optimizer
- pluralist, pluralizer
- psychologist, psychologizer
- realist, realizer
- secularist, secularizer
- terrorist, terrorizer
- theorist, theorizer

However, it turns out that in this particular case, the OED defines both to be exactly the same:

> **plagiarizer** = **plagiarist**

---

<sub>1. There being something like 154 such *-ist/-izer* pairs in the OED.  This is a little under half the total number of *-izer* words (323), but only a very small portion of the total number of *-ist* words therein attested (3,774).</sub>

Comment: Okay, T. I owe you an upvote.

Comment: I don't know how many other pairs I'd distinguish, but I assume everyone would accept *economist, economizer* as having two very different and distinct meanings.

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score -2):

Doing it once makes one a *plagiarizer*. Doing it as a profession makes one a *plagiarist*.

*Plagiarizer* may generally be used in the context of or with reference to a specific incident while *plagiarist* is possible better suited in the context of regular practice.

[emphasis mine:]

> In that the book had not yet appeared in print, immediate action was taken by APA to “go after” the **plagiarizer** and, of course, to pull the three stolen biographies from the volume.
>   (*Handbook of Ethics in Quantitative Methodology*, [p.489](http://books.google.com/books?id=DKgYxsYQDqsC&pg=PA489&dq=plagiarizer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HLZbUdHpGIW8rAfZuYDwDw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw))

Compare,

> **Plagiarists** have long posed a threat to authors. At the same time, **plagiarists** add value to the very same process they otherwise threaten, insofar as the real or imagined menace …
>   (*Plagiarism: alchemy and remedy in higher education*, [p.49](http://books.google.com/books?id=KxG3BlhEhHIC&pg=PA49&dq=plagiarist&hl=en&sa=X&ei=irdbUYPXCMnIrQe8nYCACg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBzgU))

Usage may vary.

Comment: I think that's a spurious distinction. Not being overly familiar with its use, I just typed [plagiarizer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plagiarizer&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in to Google Books. The second entry in the list says ***Chronic** plagiarizers often lack a secure sense of personal identity*, which hardly fits with only doing it *once*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, and you're wrong! :) I too noticed the entry with *Chronic plagiarizers*, so yes it's there. However, we apply the adjective *chronic* to say that  something is 'Persisting for a long time or constantly recurring.' So you are wrong in asserting *plagiarizer* 'hardly fits with only doing it once.' **Else why would the adjective be needed?** It proves the noun per se is non-recurrent.

Comment: It may be incidental that you used an example that proves the contrary. :)

Comment: I guess if you start from the position that your distinction is generally known and made, you can make a case for that one particular instance being supportive. But it can just as easily be seen as detractive. FWIW, *habitual plagiarist* occurs less than 25 times as often as *habitual plagiarizer*, whereas the single word *plagiarist* is over 30 times more common than *plagiarizer*. The sample sizes involving *habitual* are too small to be definitive, but taken at face value those numbers certainly undermine your distinction.

Comment: Apparently I'm not getting e-mails upon answers. I didn't know this as I've never asked a question before. But anyway, thanks for the response, that's a possible distinction I didn't consider.

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz re: e-mail notifications, you can raise a question on Meta meta.english.stackexchange.com where it will catch the attention of the right people.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now you see precisely the point I'm trying to make. ***Habitual** plagiarizer*, because the adjective is *required* there. **Habitual plagiarist* is a redundancy.  *Plagiarist* doesn't need that adjective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It may be incidental that you used an example that proves the contrary. :)

Comment: @Kris: In the final analysis, there's obviously no "objective" standard by which we can ascertain the meaning of a word - to paraphrase Humpty Dumpty, words mean what people *think* they mean. If you *think* this *plagiarist/plagiariser* distinction exists, then you can observe it in your own usages. Maybe sometimes the difference will be significant, and maybe some people will think the same as you, so they'll understand exactly what you mean. But I wouldn't, unless you explicitly pointed it out to me at the time. And I doubt I'd remember it for the *next* time it came up (if ever! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. Lol.